# Finding logs relevant to a specific app in adb logcat

Tags: android, windows, debugging, adb

I am not using Android Studio, so when coding or debugging an application, I send the .apk with:

```
adb install -r test.apk
```

and run it. Recently, since [using `Thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47743732/1422096), I get a `Unfortunately, app has stopped` crash. I tried to use:

```
adb logcat
```

but it is totally impossible to see anything in it, because I see hundreds of lines per second, and it never stops.

**How to display only messages associated to a specific .apk with `adb logcat`?**

On Linux, a `grep` could probably work, but I doubt it would work with `adb` on Windows (that I am using).

Comment: try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Comment: Here's an example of a filter expression that suppresses all log messages except those with the tag "ActivityManager", at priority "Info" or above, and all log messages with tag "MyApp", with priority "Debug" or above:
`adb logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S` from [https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html]

Answer (score 1):

Add filters:

`adb logcat -v time Foo:V Bar:E *:S`

This would allow all verbose (and more severe) logs for the tag `Foo`, error logs for `Bar`, and silence everything else.

Regarding `grep`: if you install something like Git For Windows you'll be able to add `grep` as a command that can be used from a normal Windows commandline window as well.

Comment: Thanks. In order to do `adb logcat -v time com.example.example:V *:S`, should I register the tag `com.example.example` somewhere?

Comment: `Foo` corresponds to what you pass as the first argument to `Log.*` in your code (e.g. `Log.d("Foo", "This is a debug log");`

Comment: Yes, but this won't display crash reasons, does it? (I cannot `Log.d(...)` during crashs, because the app has crashed).

Comment: The Java stacktraces printed if your app crashes due to an uncaught exception will usually have something like `AndroidRuntime` as the tag.